# Ebay listing appears on different ebay sites

Tags: php, e-commerce, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I have registered one ebay shop in germany, Although when I try to list a product manually via > `sell`. It also lists on ebay.at which is austria. I want to keep them separate. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by it lists on ebay.at? Does it show up in search results or is it creating two different items?

Comment: What I mean is that when I initially list it on ebay.de, lets say the item_number is 2352432564. It shows on ebay.de/itm/item_number, but it also shows on ebay.at/itm/item_number. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Ah :) Thanks for the comment. The item_id is unique irrespective of the site. They will show up in all sites if the item is available, irrespective of the listing site as long as the item is available.